# List of lists of tuples to list of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list like

```
[[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')], [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]]
```

I want the output to be like a list of dictionaries

```
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f', 'g': 'h'}]
```

How to parse it to get the output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: convert a list of tuples into a list of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807446/python-convert-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-list-of-dict)

Comment: @hyperTrashPanda It's not a duplicate. The algorithm is totally different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of tuples to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522446/list-of-tuples-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be using a list comprehension containing a dictionary comprehension for the inner dictionaries:

```
l = [ [('a' , 'b'), ('c' , 'd')] , [('e' , 'f') , ('g' , 'h')] ]

[{k:v for k,v in i} for i in l]
# [{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f', 'g': 'h'}]
```

---

Or directly mapping with the `dict` constructor:

```
list(map(dict, l))
# [{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f', 'g': 'h'}]
```

Note that this last method works as `dict` accepts iterables where each item in the iterable are themselved iterables with exactly two objects, which is this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this list-comprehension :

```
>>> l = [ [('a' , 'b'), ('c' , 'd')] , [('e' , 'f') , ('g' , 'h')] ]
>>> [dict(k) for k in l]
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f', 'g': 'h'}]
```

You can directly make a list of tuples (each having a pair of items) into a dictionary with `dict()`.